# Recommend a tool/browser extension to fill forms

Tags: manual-testing, browsers

Can anyone recommend a tool (free) or browser extension (preferably for Chrome) when filling in forms from a front end view.

I've come across Form Filler for Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo - although it populates random characters and I would like to set specific data for each field. This tool enables users to add page ID's, class and name, but it still generates random characters. This would be ideal if you could set specified data to be input per field.

I'm not wishing to use WebDriver at this stage as it'll take too long to write the scripts at the initial testing stage.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Agree. If you want to avoid webdriver here, you may want to use [SeleniumIDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/), which allows you to create quick scripts (that ultimately get driven by webdriver) to play back and test functionality.

Comment: I agree with bretjb. With selenium ide you can record your script once and then you can just change the input values and run it there after...

Answer (score 1):

> The form fuzzer extension of chrome looks simple and easy to use for
> filling up of forms. Here is the link to it -
> https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/form-fuzzer/cbpplldpcdcfejdaldmnfhlodoadjhii
> Th for fuzzer extension doesn't exist anymore.

Here are a few other extensions:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fake-filler/bnjjngeaknajbdcgpfkgnonkmififhfo?hl=en
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autofill/nlmmgnhgdeffjkdckmikfpnddkbbfkkk?hl=en
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lazy-fuzzer/ghmopjhkkcjplianfnijfdjjaacmbkan?hl=en

After installing the extension in chrome,

1. Right click on its icon in extension bar.
2. Go to options and select the settings and insert the values to suit your needs.
3. Save the settings and whenever you need to fill in a form just click(left click) the icon once and viola, your characters will appear in form fields.

Comment: this extension is ideal for me. Just what I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: Glad to know this worked out well for you! Have fun... :)

Comment: This is a dead link.

Comment: Yes @AllInOne, Seems like the extension is no longer working. I've referenced a few other extensions. Also you can search for other in the chrome web store.

Answer (score 0):

This is one thing that record-playback automation tools do quite well; if you've got a short-term one-off task for inputting a lot of data, in a fairly consistent way through some screens, then they're what you need. Quick to record the test, quick to make the script data-driven, and quick to play back.

Answer (score 0):

The best one I've used so far is iMacro, its an extension comes with IE and Mozilla. You can easily record your action and play it back. Its easily compatible and can be further extended using VB script. 
Best thing you can run this extension by opening a new window or on any already open window.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using tool I created: https://fill.ly (or link directly to webstore: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/filly/imemmdpjflmkjjomahchpaijgfhnpdmp

It has everything you need: saving and restoring forms with one click or hotkey (by default alt + shift + 1 for showing list of forms, and shift + alf + 2 for saving current form).

Also it can fill any form on the internet with your personal data.

Hope it will be useful for you.